# Equivalent function num_rows in MYSQL for PDO for use with SQL-server

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

In mysql num_rows would return to me the number of selected records in a SELECT statement.  I am using PDO now for SQL server and I am trying to find an equivalent function.  I have tried the following but they do not work/ give what I am after.

```
 $sql = "select * from tracker WHERE tms_key='575'";

 $result = $conn->query($sql);

 $count = $result->fetchColumn());



 echo '$count: '.$count.'<br>';



 foreach ($result as $row){



                 echo $row['cucm_tmsDeviceName'];

 }
```

This just outputs:

```
 $count: 575
```

Second approach:

```
 $sql = "select * from tracker WHERE tms_key='575'";

 $result = $conn->query($sql);

 $count = $result->rowCount();



 echo '$count: '.$count.'<br>';



 foreach ($result as $row){



                 echo $row['cucm_tmsDeviceName'];

 }
```

This outputs:

```
 $count: -1

 GMVC AR BA VICENTE LOPEZ COBALT
```

Comment: Try `select COUNT(*) as count` then place that into a reference as you did for the `$row`.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner sorry, i'm a little unsure what you advising me.  Please could you write it out?

Comment: `select COUNT(*) as count`  then `foreach ($result as $row){



                 echo $row['count'];

 }` - that should do it. If not, remove the foreach and just echo as you did above.